# Javascript causes browser to hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Even though console log give the while expression as false the loop runs infinetly.

```
var tile_height;
$(document).ready(function(){
tile_height = $("#department > .front").height();
        });
        function tile_animate(e){
        console.log(($('> .front',e).css("height") > '0px') && ($('> .back',e).height() < tile_height));
        while(($('> .front',e).css("height") > '0px') && ($('> .back',e).height() <  tile_height)) 
            {
                $('> .front',e).animate({height: '-=1px'});
                $('> .back',e).animate({height: '+=1px'});
            }
        }
```

I have tried it using if statement as a recursive function but that too does not work. Using while causes browser to stop responding. The html code that calls the function is

HTML code

```
<div class="tiles" id="gallery" onmouseover="javascript:tile_animate(this)">
    <div class="front">
    </div>
    <div class="back">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe your code is make infinite loop!

Comment: agreed - likely an infinite loop - maybe add a break point and investigate?

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: try to avoid comparing strings like `$('> .front',e).css("height") > '0px'` it's better if you convert to numbers before comparing...

Comment: changed to `$('> .front',e).height() > 0` but still not working

Comment: could you provide this on fiddle if you are still having problems

Comment: fiddle link [https://jsfiddle.net/j1s7fgvq/]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are using a loop while hovering. Better, is that you use the jQuery animate in a style and apply it when necessary.

However, the way you have described the problem, it looks like you will shrink the div once - there is nothing to restore it afterwards.
I noticed that the div was named 'department' but the JavaScript was looking for 'gallery' - so I changed that...

So, to perfrom this as you have your code now, a few tweaks are in order:

Remove the while loop and perform a check instead while hovering.

The check is to see if the animation is already occurring.

If the animation is occurring, ignore the hover.

If the animation is not already occurring, set a flag to say it is, and perform the required animation - not reduce the size of the div pixel by pixel (this is what the animation does for you).

When done, the div will have a height of 0px (and cannot be hovered over again).

If you wanted to restore the div later, then store its original dimensions prior to the animation, and restore them when needed (not forgetting to reset the inLoop variable)...

```js
var tile_height;
var inLoop = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  tile_height = $("#gallery > .front").height();
});

function tile_animate(e) {
  if (!inLoop && ($('> .front', e).css("height") > '0px') && ($('> .back', e).height() < tile_height)) {
    inLoop = true;
    $('> .front', e).animate({
      height: '0px'
    });
    $('> .back', e).animate({
      height: tile_height
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery why don't you just embed your code and trigger the function from an event handler in JS:

```js
var tile_height;

$(document).ready(function() {
  tile_height = $("#department > .front").height();
  $("#gallery").mouseover(function() {
    e = this;
    console.log(($('> .front', e).css("height") > '0px') && ($('> .back', e).height() < tile_height));
    while (($('> .front', e).css("height") > '0px') && ($('> .back', e).height() < tile_height)) {
      $('> .front', e).animate({
        height: '-=1px'
      });
      $('> .back', e).animate({
        height: '+=1px'
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="tiles" id="gallery">
  <div class="front">front</div>
  <div class="back">back</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Still causes browser to hang

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is single threaded. In particular your code has to finish execution before another thread can start.  The other thread you are really interested in is Jquery's animation loop which by default loops on a 14 ms timer thread.

In consequence your while loop is running infinitely because animation code never runs to decrement the height you are testing and expect to reach zero.